# extern in objective-C; do they behave differently than C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I required to share a const value between two files; so rather than keeping a magical number I decided to use a `const` variable.
So I created a `global` variable `const int viewTag = 100;` in my `appDelegate.m`
Then accessed it as `extern const int viewTag;` but I got following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"viewTag", referenced from:
  -[xxxViewController launchxxx] in libxxx_iPad.a(xxxViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But the above thing is perfectly leagal in normal C,C++ env. can anybody throw some light?

Update: putting `extern const int viewTag;` in header and importing that header works, but I really don't want to do that for a single `const int`

Comment: I guess putting it into the .h file for your app delegate tells the compiler to expose that to the linker? Anyway, if your variable is called viewTag, why is it in the app delegate at all? It should be defined in your view controller (or, ideally, as an IBOutlet and connected using a xib?)

Comment: hey @deanWombourne, it's because I want to display a passcode screen on the topmost/desirable view. The `viewTag` helps me to do that.

Comment: Could you create a UIView subclass that was a passcode screen that knew how to render itsef without the need for view tags?

Comment: The `PassCodeScreen` require either the `ParentView` reference OR it's `tag`.

Comment: Why does it; surely it will just be displayed as the topmost view if it's a login screen - you can get the window's view and use that as it's parent?

Comment: ohh ya, that's how I'ld really do; if it's my code ;-). Well, I was fixing a bug; at the same time keeping the changes minimum. I'll definitely try to propose this ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting:

```
extern const int viewTag;
```

in `appDelegate.h`, then importing this header where you need access to `viewTag`.

Comment: well, sorry I forgot to mention the above suggestion works and in fact it is what I had did currently. But I really don't want to import an `.h` just for a single `const int`.

Comment: Sure. You'll often find it is objective-c style to have extern's for global-like things, and you find extern's in many Apple headers.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use #define viewTag 100 in .pch file.

But I think, the best way is to create .h file with constants and include where you want

Comment: Doesn't need to be -- probably shouldn't be -- in the .pch file.

Comment: ya, but using `.pch` is bad; ok for small projects but we have 100 MBs of source code, if you change a single line in `.pch` all app re-compiles ;-(

Comment: I think the best way is to create .h file with constants and include where you want.